# Multiple Markers on Google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following:

```
    var SampleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.379, -113.53),
        map: map,
        title: "Hello World!"
    });
```

To add a marker to my map, but how would I use the same to say iterate over an array of latlngs? I wish to add multiple markers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example

Comment: [Example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply wrap that in a function and call it in any loop :

```
function createMarker(latitude, longitude, myTitle){

    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        map: map,
        title: myTitle
    });

}
```

have fun.